# Как перехватить нажатия клавиш физической клавиатуры из сервиса?

Tags: android

Есть задача: по нажатию определенной клавиши на клавиатуре (или сочетания клавиш) запускать определенное действие/приложение.
Из документации понял, что нажатие обычных клавиш можно обработать только из `Activity`, а из сервиса только `Media Button`, но при этом необходимо сохранить работоспособность клавиш для остальных приложений (например, при нажатии `Play` запускать проигрывание).

В манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

В `onCreate()` сервиса регистрирую ресивер:

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(this, RemoteControlReceiver.class));
IntentFilter mediaButton = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
registerReceiver(remoteControlReceiver, mediaButton);
```

Класс `RemoteControlReceiver`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RemoteControlReceiver: received key event = " + event.getKeyCode());
}
```

Данный код единожды перехватил нажатие `Play`, после этого нажатия перехватываются плеером.
Подскажите как осуществить задумку!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение самостоятельно, может кому-то будет полезно... Способ с `Media Button` не дал результата, поэтому пошел по альтернативному пути через `AccessibilityService`. Реализация:

В манифесте добавил описание сервиса:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"     
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
  android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
         </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>
```

xml с параметрами сервиса:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
    android:settingsActivity="ru.atic.autodroid.StartScreen"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
     />
```

ну и сам сервис:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {

    final String LOG_TAG = "mLog";

    @Override
    protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyAccessibilityService: onKeyEvent: action = " + event.getAction() +
                                                            "; key code = " + event.getKeyCode() +
                                                            "; scan code = " + event.getScanCode() +
                                                            "; meta state = " + event.getMetaState() +
                                                            "; key = " + event.getNumber());
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case 8:
                Intent intent8 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.bambuna.podcastaddict");
                intent8.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent8);
                break;
            case 9:
                Intent intent9 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.pasha.kissfm");
                intent9.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent9);
                break;
            case 10:
                Intent intent10 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                intent10.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent10);
                break;
        }
        return super.onKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

По нажатию на клавиатуре "1", "2", "3" запускаются соответствующие приложения.
Конечно сервис для работы требует соответствующего разрешения от пользователя, но меня такой вариант устраивает.

Comment: *Конечно сервис для работы требует соответствующего разрешения от пользователя* -- оно и понятно, иначе реализация трояна-кейлоггера была бы плёвым делом.